# I am trying to write a ps script that silently runs all .exe in a directory

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will run all .exe files within a directory called "C:\drivers"

My current script

```
$exe = "*.exe"
$exelist = get-childitem "C:\drivers\*.exe"

foreach ($exe in $exelist){
        start-process -wait -filepath $exelist -argumentlist "/S" -passthru
}
```

I receive

```
Start-Process : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'FilePath'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:5 char:39
+         start-process -wait -filepath $exelist -argumentlist "/S" -pa ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

The script works if there is only one .exe file in the directory, however if there are multiple that is the error I receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) syntax:

> ```
> Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> …
> ```

but you pass a `System.Object[]` instead of string in your

```
start-process -wait -filepath $exelist …
```

The following code snippet should work:

```
$exe = "*.exe"
$exelist = Get-ChildItem "C:\drivers" -Filter $exe

foreach ($exe in $exelist){
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $exe.FullName -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did fix it and it runs as it should. Out of curiosity, why do you have to use ".FullName" for the script to work?

Comment: @Ambre Get-Childitem does not just return the file names as a string in an array. Rather it contains complex objects with multiple other properties like "last modified date" and so on. But the parameter -FilePath of Start-Process expectes a string argument, not an object. So that is why with ".FullName" we extract just the file path from the complex object and pass that to the cmdlet